# How can we pass retry count of event grid into azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventgrid

I have one azure function subscribed to event grid ,now i have 3 as max retry count,i want to pass retry count every time when my azure function called.
For example if in first call i want to pass 1 as retry count then if its fails and retrying my azure function second time then i want to pass retry count as 2.is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this value only for the **HttpTrigger** function from the header:

```
aeg-delivery-count
```

I do recommend to make a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/34324771-better-error-handling-for-eventgrid-calls-that-you#comments) to the Azure Function team to pass all *aeg* headers to the *EventGridTrigger* bindings.